# Best way to reorder dom elements based on json data

Tags: jquery, json, dom, jtemplate

Once I create dom elements base on json data with jtemplates, what is the best way to reorder those elements based on changes to the json data (sorting, filtering, etc.).

Comment: Can you not sort the JSON stuff first, and then create the elements?

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan.  @Pointy, yes sorting the json data and creating the elements with jtemplates works fine.  But afterwords, on the client, I want to be able to sort and filter the json data and reflect those changes on the dom elements by moving them around and showing/hiding them.

Answer (score 1):

So the method I'm using to solve this right now is I added a numbered index to each of my templated sections of html like so:

```
<div id="list">
    <div id="items-start"></div>
    {#foreach $T as item}
    <div id="item-{$T.item$index}" class="item">
        ...lots of stuff...
    </div>
    {#/for}
</div>
```

Then in my json items I added an attribute called InitialIndex to keep track of which dom item is associated with each item in the json.  This way after I make any changes to my json data I can call this simple function to apply the changes to the dom:

```
function applyListChanges(items) {
    $('.item').hide();
    for (var item in items) {
        var index = items[item].InitialIndex;
        $('#items-start').append($('#item-' + index));
        $('#item-' + index).show();
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you have a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest & easiest way of doing this would be as follows:

1) Re-order / sort your list of JSON objects
2) Clear the DOM list (or remove the list depending on your jTemplate), something like this

```
$('#list').html('');
```

3) Then re-populate the list by re-runing the jTemplate on the JSON object.

Keep in mind that rendering a list to the DOM using a templating engine is fast, makes your code much cleaner and doesn't require any complex logic to map JSON objects to their DOM equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Create new element, add child elements to this element, add parent element to the DOM.